# Having trouble converting hex string to double

Tags: struct, binary, hex, double, python-3.6

I have a little-endian hex string (for example, 'E61000003C9BFAE53893') that I'm trying to convert to a double. I've tried the following:

```
struct.unpack('<d', binascii.unhexlify('E61000003C9BFAE53893'))
```

but I keep getting

```
struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 8 bytes
```

I checked the output of binascii.unhexlify('E61000003C9BFAE53893'), and it looks correct:

```
>> print (binascii.unhexlify('E61000003C9BFAE53893'))

b'\xe6\x10\x00\x00<\x9b\xfa\xe58\x93'
```

so I'm not sure what the issue is.

For some context, I have a bunch of coordinate data encoded as WKB, but geopandas only supports WKT. I thought it would be easy to write a function to convert one to the other (or WKB to floats), but it's proving more challenging that I expected.

Answer (score 0):

`0xE61000003C9BFAE53893` is too long to be a double. A double is 8 bytes and that is 9...ish? If you take a look at the second to last in your output, it is "`0xe58`".

`struct.unpack` only accepts 8 byte buffers, as per the error message.

Comment: Turns out the coordinate data was actually stored as EWKB, not just WKB, so it included 4 bytes of SRID (Spatial Reference system ID). That explains why I thought I was dealing with two 10-byte floats, when I was actually dealing with two 8-byte floats and 4 bytes of SRID data.